# can I use object oriented header file in C program

Tags: c, oop

I am familiar in programming with C++ and its Object Oriented nature. Now I am supposed to work in C these days. I still want to use the header files I have already prepared in past which are Object Oriented(use class, constructor, destructor etc.). Please help me knowing about the hidden facts while doing this. Although the program doesn't give syntax erro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use C for object-oriented programming.  I do this.  But the C language does not help you.

I will discuss using C for object-oriented programming.  But please understand I am talking about practices, not about anything built into the language.

In C++, you can declare a `class`, and it can have `public`, `private`, and `protected` parts.  In C, you can declare a `struct`, and everything in the `struct` will be public.  In C++, a `class` can have associated functions; in C, functions are global.  (In C, functions and variables declared `static` will be private to a single source file, but global within that file.  Functions and variables not declared `static` are global through the whole program.  There is no way to declare members of a `struct` to be private, although you are free to use a naming convention that makes it clear that some member variable are intended to be private.)

In C++, you have name spaces, and a `class` forms a name space.  In C, there is only one global name space.

In C++, there is operator overloading; not in C.

In C++, when you declare functions as member functions, the compiler will magically make a `this` pointer available.  In C, you can make member functions but you must explicitly give them an argument equivalent to a `this` pointer.

In C++, the compiler will arrange to all your constructor and destructor for you.  In C, you must explicitly call your functions.

So, then, here is how to do object-oriented programming in C:

First, declare a struct to hold the data in your object.  I recommend using a `typedef` so you can refer to it conveniently.  Let's imagine you are writing a physics simulator for automobiles; let's say your struct will be `typedef`ed as type `CAR`.

Now you write a constructor and destructor function.  Since the compiler doesn't help youit is worthwhile to make the effort to do it., you can't use a `~` in the name of the destructor.  We will imagine your functions are declared as `CAR *PcarNew();` and `void FreePcar(CAR *pcar);`.

Now you write member functions.  A function to start the engine of the car might be `void StartEnginePcar(CAR *pcar);`.  (If you also have trucks, you might have a `void StartEnginePtruck(TRUCK *ptruck);`; if you also have buses, you might have `void StartEnginePbus(BUS *pbus);`; and so on.  There is only one global namespace.)  As there is no `this` pointer, the first argument is an explicit reference to an instance of the class (i.e. a pointer allocated by calling the constructor).

Note that in C++ you could have an object named `c` that was an instance of `class car` and you could say `c.start_engine()`; the C++ compiler knows you mean the `start_engine()` member function from `class car`.  You can have any number of functions in C++ with the same name, each a member of a different class, and C++ will use name spaces to keep track of them.  In C you don't get anything like that, and every function name must be unique.  This is why function names in C object-oriented programming usually have the name of the "class" in the function name itself, as in `StartEnginePcar()`.  (Some people would likely just use `StartEngineCar()` or `CarStartEngine()` but I use a particular coding style that encourages the style I used in my first examples.  Use whatever coding style you like, of course.)

(As noted in a comment below, in C you can put a function pointer inside a struct and call it with the `->` operator, but this is best used for cases where you don't know in advance what the function will be, not to try to duplicate some object-oriented syntax.  If you need to do something like a `virtual` pointer in C++, you would use a function pointer in your "class" `struct`.)

Object-oriented programming is definitely not as nice in C as in C++, but I do think that explicitly following the OOP model in C can help your programs be easier to design and to understand.

Comment: c.start_engine(c) you can actually do this in c using function pointers, though you have to specify a reference to the struct explicitly, C++ does this implicitly, the function will still have somewhat global scope :( ... still good post :)

Comment: I'll rewrite that section to make my meaning more clear.  In C++, you can simply name your function `start_engine()` and in other classes you can have other functions that are also called `start_engine()` and through the magic of namespaces it works.  In C, each function must have a unique name.  You have to look at long function names like `StartEnginePcar()` all the time.

Comment: yeah I agree, but what I meant to say is that you can sort of attach functions to structs using function pointers, so they resemble c++ objects even more, but yeah C namespaces can get incredibly crowded ...

Answer (score 3):

[C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) is not an Object Oriented Language.

C is an [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) ([procedural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming)) systems implementation language.

Assuming you have gcc compiler, try to compile with this options:

```
gcc -std=c99 replacewithyoursourcefilename.c -o execProgram
```

And you will see the compiler errors.

Is it an option to rewrite your C++ code to pure C?

I recommend you to check the C [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) of StackOverflow to learn more about the language.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your elaborative answer. I am laughing what I was trying to do. That was nice response of you.

Comment: anytime @user1444034 can you mark my response(or any other that you like) as the "answer" to your question please? Only for a matter of documentation, I am sure that you are not the only one that has that question and it could help someone else in the future...

Answer (score 1):

No! C standard was written before C++ standards and therefore all newer constructs give syntax errors in C. You can encapsulate C++ related things with

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
..
#endif
```

To hide them from C compiler if this helps you to cope with compatibility issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really helpful for me.

Comment: the // comment was invented in c++ and later adopted in c ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I still want to use the header files I have already prepared in past which are Object Oriented(use class, constructor, destructor etc.)

So your header files are written in C++, making use of classes, which is C++-only syntax not available in C. So the answer ist "No, you cannot use C++ classes in C".

What you can do is either

- try to encapsulate your C++ code in a library, wrap it with an API written in C. That will only work when you have a C++ compiler available on the platform you are working, but I guess you have not (why else would you bother with C in that case?)
- rewrite your C++ classes in C, keeping an object oriented style with the C language elements. [Here](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf) is a complete online book how to do object oriented programming with C.

Answer (score 0):

You can search "mix c and c++" in StackOverflow to find the solution.